# OpenStack keystoneclient get user by name

Tags: openstack, keystone, openstack-horizon

I know it is possible to get a user by id but all I have available is the name.  Anyone know how to get a user by name using the keystone client v 2.0?

```
from keystoneclient.v2_0 import client
keystone = client.Client(username=USER,
                         password=PASS,
                         tenant_name=TENANT_NAME,
                         auth_url=KEYSTONE_URL)
user = keystone.users.get(USER_ID)
```

need something like the following ********
keystone.users.getByName(USER_NAME)

Answer (score 3):

Figured out a way to do this from keystoneclient.  Sort of.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from keystoneclient.v2_0 import client
from keystoneclient import utils

keystone = client.Client(username='admin',
                         password='stack',
                         tenant_name='demo',
                         auth_url='http://192.168.122.236:5000/v2.0/')


def do_user_get(kc, args):
    """Display user details."""
    user = utils.find_resource(kc.users, args)
    utils.print_dict(user._info)

do_user_get (keystone, 'demo')
```

Makes use of utils in addition to the client.users

There are some extra parsing functions in util you might want to check out.

Comment: this stuff needs better documentation.  ping anne gentle on the openstack-dev list if you want to help fill that out.